# python - grab data between 2 constant chars

Tags: python

Here is an example of the data:

```
x = '[ 5 | 6 | 7 [' # number 1
y = '[ 10 | 11 | 7 [' # number 2
```

For number one, I just want 5. Number 2, I just want 10. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to isolate the 2nd space-separated field. Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for this:

```
for s in ('[ 5 | 6 | 7 [', '[ 10 | 11 | 7 ['):
  print s, " => ", int(s.split()[1])
```

If you want all of the numeric fields, use [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to determine which fields are numeric, and [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to create a new list:

```
for s in ('[ 5 | 6 | 7 [', '[ 10 | 11 | 7 ['):
  print filter(str.isdigit, s.split())
```

If you don't know if there are spaces around each number, you can isolate the numbers using [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
for s in ('[ 5 | 6 | 7 [', '[ 10 | 11 | 7 ['):
  print re.findall('\d+', s)
```